# Render content from page.tpl.php in ajax callback, without the html.tpl.php

Tags: theming, ajax

I am attempting to render an entire page through an ajax callback using either custom javascript or drupals `ajax_deliver`.  The issue is that it is trying to render the entire page and I simply want it to render what is in a custom `page.tpl.php` file created.  I have found a solution around this using a `$_GET` in the `html.tpl.php` but it seems hacky to me.

Basically I am rendering only the `$page` variable if a `$_GET` is set, if not render it as normal.  Is there any functions or way to simply render all the regions in a page, minus what is in the `html.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [AJAXify Pages](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxify_pages) (dev version only)

> Module to ajaxify site browsing and navigation. For instance, it
>   allows for continuous audio playback via Background Audio module while
>   changing the content of the pages.

or [AJAXify](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxify) module (D5 only)

> You can always create links that load other pages via AJAX but you
>   will still load a full page HTML while you may only need a single HTML
>   element from the loaded page and this is what AJAXify focuses on.

If youre not planning to use any of these module take a look at [THIS](http://drupalcode.org/project/ajaxify.git/blob/c9f28481b29239c44e010d44e29127412eccca3e:/ajaxify.module#l20) function
to get some idea.

Comment: Thanks those seem so be helpful.  I also found another way which basically hooks into the theme preprocess html/page and if i have an argument through the get then it will return a different html.tpl.php and different page.tpl.php page, which seems a little hacky to me so that would be last resort.  Thanks for the help!